# Load .DMP oracle file from local machine to RDS Oracle

Tags: oracle, import

I am wandering around and didn't get an answer to this question.
is there any way to import Oracle .dmp file stored on a local machine to RDS Oracle?
If Yes how to do it?
Else why it's not possible to do so as other databases gave the flexibility to do these kinds of imports through more than one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. When you import data with Oracle Data Pump, you must transfer the dump file that contains the data from the source database to the target database**. You can transfer the dump file using an Amazon S3 bucket or by using a database link between the two databases.

If your local machine contains a database and you have a network connection between your on-premises database and your Oracle RDS , then you can use NETWORK_LINK, although I don't recommend it. It is much better to tranfer the file using S3 bucket.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html](http://AWS%20Importing%20Oracle%20Datapump)

Comment: Hi @Roberto Hernandez first of all thank you for taking time and answering the question , secondly what will be the ideal way if someone provides whole oracle DMP to upload it in RDS Oracle.

Comment: @karnish, the first method, Amazon S3 bucket. Network link can be painfully slow in Amazon RDS. Please, I would appreciate if you upvote the answer.